# paypal checkout.min.js slowing down site

Tags: magento2

this is my situation with checkout.min.js loaded from the PayPal servers.
It loads in 4 secs.

[image]

My site is loading in 8 secs (https://gtmetrix.com/), any ideas in how i can reduce this loading time?

Thank You

Answer (score 1):

Me too, i have the same issue. Just try to download the file and save it in your module `Vendor/Module/view/frontend/web/js/checkout.js` then edit `vendor/magento/module-paypal/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js` with

```
...
paypalInContextExpressCheckout: 'Vendor_Module/js/checkout'
...
```

flush `pub/static/*` and check if you resolve the issue. If yes, you could refactor this fix to maintenable customisation.